# insert new line when negative + positive pattern is found using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Got a bunch of txt files that need to be cleaned and parsed properly. 
I need to break lines when pattern "SP." is found but not when pattern "ASSERT. SP." is found.

Sample content:

```
    SP. 247 for specific issues no really solved
    ASSERT. SP. 4532 no so valuable it depends on primary conditions
    At first location in London City SP. 3901 must be applied
    ASSERT. SP. 23245 must be followed by procedure SP. 8236 in all steps
    Special tools are needed for SP. 9734 to be accomplished
```

Desired result:

```
        SP. 247 for specific issues no really solved
        ASSERT. SP. 4532 no so valuable it depends on primary conditions
        At first location in London City 
        SP. 3901 must be applied
        ASSERT. SP. 23245 must be followed by procedure 
        SP. 8236 in all steps
        Special tools are needed for 
        SP. 9734 to be accomplished
```

My first approach is using **regex** to find if **"SP."** is **not** preceded by a dot and then replace by "newline + SP."  but no success so far.

```
sed -r 's/([^\.] )(SP\. )/\nSP\. /g'
```

Comment: do you have those spaces at beginning of file or just formatting issue here? also, is `perl` solution okay?

Comment: just formatting. Perl not allowed. Only sed

Comment: too bad then.. easy to do in perl... `perl -pe 's/ASSERT\.\s*SP(*SKIP)(*F)|SP\./\n$&/g'`

Comment: Perl worked great Sundeep . Sadly must be sed

Comment: with a little tweak, your sed should work well... `sed -r 's/([^.] )(SP\. )/\1\n\2/g'`

Comment: Sundeep you've proved to be very valuable. Two working suggestions first in perl, then in sed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a little tweak of `sed` solution posted in OP

```
sed -r 's/([^.] )(SP\. )/\1\n\2/g'
```

The issue with `s/([^\.] )(SP\. )/\nSP\. /g` is that it discards `([^\.] )`. Also `.` need not be escaped inside `[]` as well as in replacement section

Answer (score 1):

Usually same tasks can be solved via substitution unhanged part by rare symbol then return it back

```
sed '
    s/\(^\s*\|ASSERT\. \)SP\./\1\a/g
    s/SP\./\n&/g
    s/\a/SP./g
    '
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
sed -r '
    # for lines without "ASSERT.", add a newline before "SP."
    # unless it is only preceded by whitespace
    /ASSERT\./! s/^(.*[^[:blank:]].*)(SP\.)/\1\n\2/

    # for lines containing "ASSERT.", add a newline before the last "SP."
    s/^(.*ASSERT\..*SP\..*)(SP\..*)/\1\n\2/
' file
```